# Infinitely repeated game, discount factor and deviating from strategy

Tags: game-theory

I have an exercise in Steven Tadelis Game theory Introduction book (10.2) :

**Grim Trigger**: Consider the infinitely repeated game with discount factor
$δ < 1$ of the following variant of the Prisoner’s Dilemma:

[image]

a) For which values of the discount factor δ can the players support the
pair of actions (M, C) played in every period?

b)For which values of the discount factor δ can the players support the
pair of actions (T,L) played in every period? Why is your answer
different from that for (a)?

I have answered [(a) in this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/37286/discount-factor-and-deviating-from-strategy-game-theory)

Now I would like to check if my (b) is correct:

In order to find which strategies the players would deviate to, we find the nash equilibrium of the game, which is $(0,0)$. So, this means that player 1 plays $B$ all the time and player 2 plays $R$ all the time , given that they would deviate to any other strategy than (T,L). So, the payoff for both of them given that they stay on $(6,6)$ is :

$6+\delta 6+\delta^2 6+...=6+\delta\sum^{\infty}_{t=1}\delta^{t-1}=6+6\delta/(1-\delta)$

And if they deviate from (6,6), they will have a payoff of $8$ the first timestep they move from (6,6) and then a payoff of $0$'s afterwards(since the opposing player(s) would play the nash equilibrium strategy, as they would not like to play the same strategy as (6,6) and be losing $-2$ all the time ) :

$8+0\delta+0\delta^2+...=8$

So, in order not to deviate from (6,6), the payoff should be greater than the deviating strategy, so we calculate for which $\delta$ values they don't deviate:

$6+6\delta/(1-\delta)\geq 8 \Leftrightarrow \delta \geq 1/4$

So, for $\delta \geq 1/4$ they stay on the (T,L) strategy forever.

The reason the answer is different from [(a) (my previous question)](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/37286/discount-factor-and-deviating-from-strategy-game-theory) is that the strategies they deviate from are different. So, to not deviate from 6 to 8, they would need a bigger incentive to stay on track. And for them to not deviate from 4 to 5, they wouldn't be as "motivated" to move from 4 to 5 since the difference is lower than 8-6=1, hence they need a lower incentive to stay "on track".

Would my reasoning be correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.